# Does Insert Overwrite deletes the data and partition in hive?

Tags: hive, partitioning, overwrite

I am creating a partition on year and month. suppose previous partition exist in target hive table is `year = 2018 and month = 10 and month = 11`. Now new data is coming having `year = 2018 and month = 11` only.
So my question is will insert overwrite remove the data and partition for `month = 10`? 
Please suggest me a solution as I want to remove data and partition for `month = 10` too.
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to remove the old partitions everytime when a new month data arrives?

Comment: Yes , this is the requirement , FYI  target table is

Answer (score 0):

When Hive tries to “INSERT OVERWRITE” to a partition of an external table under an existing directory, depending on whether the partition definition already exists in the metastore or not, Hive will behave differently:

a) if partition definition does not exist, it will not try to guess where the target partition directories are (either static or dynamic partitions), so it will not be able to delete existing files under those partitions that will be written to

b) if partition definition does exist, it will attempt to remove all files under the target partition directory before writing new data into those directories.

So In a nutshell, in your case, it will not delete the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all existing partitions and keep only the new month data, you can use `DROP PARTITION` command with comparators.

**Eg:** If there are partitions for year  2018 and month 10 and before that.  You can configure using either one

```
// If there is always only one partition
 alter table part_t drop partition (year=2003,month=1);

// If there are multiple partitions, you can use < comparator
 alter table part_t drop partition (year <2003,month<1);
```